# Android deep link to resume app

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

Is there a way for a deep link into my app to simply resume the app if it's already running and preserve the activity stack?

Lets say I have activities `A`, `B`. Both are `singleTop`.
`A` is my main activity and it is also the one that has the intent filter for the deep link.
If I open `A`, and `B` on top. Then pause the app to go to a browser to deep link into my app. It opens just `A` where I want it to have `B` on top of `A`.

Is this possible?

Comment: hi Jason did you got this to work?

Comment: unfortunately not at this moment :(

Comment: @JasonHu any solutions??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your deep link takes the app to a dummy activity C (and that is the only way to start that activity, for simplicity) and from there you find your way back to the previous activity (either A or B).

Comment: This unfortunately might work to navigate to an activty that I want but would not preserve the stack of `B` on top of `A` :(

Comment: Still am not totally sure what the end goal is, but if you are trying to get back to where the last activity (the one that was on top when launching the external app), maybe use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY when launching the browser and also use it when launching the dummy activity. Then you can call finish() in the dummy activity and it should go back the last activity?